# How Show "No record found" or "No Data Found" message in jeasyui datagrid when the grid has no rows

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datagrid, jquery-easyui

Is there any method to set EmptyMessage in easy-ui datagrid for showing a text as "No Data Found" when the datagrid is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use footer rows. When returning JSON from server, if the record count is 0, frame the footer row as "NO records found".

Refer http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=